# ERROR: 0:3: error(#279) Invalid layout qualifier 'location'

Tags: java, opengl, glsl, shader, vertex-shader

i am trying to follow a tutorial and when i try to compile the vertex shader he made i get this output:

```
Vertex shader failed to compile with the following errors:
ERROR: 0:3: error(#279) Invalid layout qualifier 'location'
ERROR: error(#273) 1 compilation errors.  No code generated
```

I use GLSL 3.2.9232 and my code :

```
#version 150

layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = vec4(0.25 * position, 1.0);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Input layout locations qualifiers (see [Vertex shader attribute index](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Layout_Qualifier_(GLSL)#Vertex_shader_attribute_index)) are introduced in in GLSL 3.30 and cannot be used in GLSL 1.50. Compare [OpenGL Shading Language 3.30 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.3.30.pdf) and  [OpenGL Shading Language 1.50 Specification](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL/specs/gl/GLSLangSpec.1.50.pdf).

Switch to glsl 3.30:

<s>`#version 150`</s>

```c
#version 330
```

If your system doesn't support GLSL 3.30, you have to remove the layout qualifier

<s>`layout (location = 0) in vec3 position;`</s>

```c
in vec3 position;
```

You can specify the attribute location with [`glBindAttribLocation`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glBindAttribLocation.xhtml) before the program is linked:

```
glBindAttribLocation(program, 0, "position"); // has to be done before glLinkProgram
glLinkProgram(program)
```

Comment: then how do i do

Comment: if i put #version 330 it would tell me the version is not supported

Comment: oh oop i thought it was all

Comment: i finally got the triangle yayyyyyyy

Comment: No problem you helped me alot